# Integer expression expected when calculating date difference

Tags: linux, bash, integer

I have this script I am building and need a bit of help.  I want to use as minimal lines of code as possible. However what I want the script to do is the following.

Backup a specified file such as authlog into a new file with the keywords I specify.

However. I also want it to back up the file if current backed up file is older than 2+ days ago and if it is newer.  Leave it alone. if (file) is older than +2 days old delete it and replace it with an updated one.

I'm getting *integer expression expected* and I'm not sure how to fix it

```
#!/bin/bash

authlog=/home/(myhomedir)/logs/backups/authlog-${current_date}
backup="$(cat /var/log/auth.log | grep -e failed -e invalid > /home/(myhomedir)/logs/backup)"
dayold=$(date -d '1 day ago' "+%Y-%m-%d")
current_date=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")

if [ $authlog -lt $dayold ] ;
    then ${backup}
        else
          echo $authlog is newer than $current_date $authlog has not been updated
if [ $authlog -eq ${current_date} ]
   then "$(rm {authlog})"
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `-lt` to compare non-numeric strings. This is why you're getting "integer expression expected". You're trying to compare a filename to a date string.

The easiest way to compare dates is by converting them to seconds since epoch (Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC). As an example, suppose I have a file called `foo.bar` and I want to check if it was last modified 3 or more days ago:

```
filetime=$(stat -c %Y foo.bar)
three_days_ago=$(date -d "3 days ago" +%s)
if [ $filetime -lt $three_days_ago ]; then
   echo "foo.bar was last modified more than 3 days ago"
fi
```

Also, your `authlog` variable does not contain a date. I'm assuming there's a missing step that you forgot.

Comment: So if i understand.  I dont need to use $current_date?
I can just do the following 
My file name to this directory and use the filetime variable to match it's date? 

 As I thought I needed the $current_date in order to match it.  But if not that's even easier.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you want to compare dates using the form `if [ $date1 -lt $date2 ]`, then `date1` and `date2` must be numeric strings, not filenames or date strings.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look deeper into this and try some other things I'm getting closer to no issues but have 1 more I'm trying to figure out.   Thanks.

Comment: Nit. better as `"converting them to seconds since epoch ..."`, which eliminates the "Seconds since what?" question and gives them a search term to learn it means `"Seconds since January 1, 1970"`, (or you can just include the starting point as well)

Comment: Heres an addition.    Googled around for it but am coming up dry.  An addition to my script.  Is there a way that.  "If logs find an invalid or failed attempt via login than the script AUTOMATICALLY takes the offensive ip and puts it into a banblock file?  


Something like   if request -eq "invalid" ;
then put (offensive ip) /banblockfile